# yAxis calculated with one series only

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm drawing a chart with Highstock.

It displays many series, and the yAxis is auto-calculated in order to show every series added to the chart. 
But one of my series is more important than the others. So I want to know if it is possible to calculate my yAxis according to only one series, no matter if some of the others series are out of the plot area? (option to set, function overwriting the calculation of the extremes...)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you know the y min max of your more important serie?

Comment: The problem is that the min and max will vary depending of the data, and data are also on a long date range (it can be more than 10 years). The min and max will then vary depending of the date range selected by the user.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/6WJtS/) is what you are looking for? Where tokyo is more important than New York

Comment: Not exactly. In your example, your two series are on different axis. In my case, all the series use the same axis. 
But I've just found a solution to my pblm thanks to you : if I link a second axis to a master one, but display only the main series on the first one, scale will be calculated only regarding to the series I want :)
Maybe you could post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this way, it's mandatory to know the min/max of the more important serie.

Create two y Axis, one for the more important serie and another invisible   :

```
yAxis : [
     {
         title: { text: 'Temperature (°C)' },
         plotLines: [{
             value: 0,
             width: 1,
             color: '#808080'
         }],
         min: {{Min Value}},
         max: {{Max Value}},
         startOnTick: false
     },{
         gridLineWidth: 0,
         minorGridLineWidth: 0,
         title: { text: '' },
         labels: {
             style:{ display: 'none' }
         },
         min: {{Same Min}},
         max: {{Same Max}},
         startOnTick: false
     }

]
```

And define yours series with the good yAxis :

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo', // More important serie
            yAxis: 0,
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York', // other serie
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [-40.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 124.1, 120.1, 114.1, 118.6, 2.5]
        }]
```

---

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3tep/LrP5F/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },
    yAxis: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }, ],
      min: -10,
      max: 30
    }, {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
          display: 'none'
        }
      },
      min: -10,
      max: 30
    }],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      yAxis: 1,
      data: [-40.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 124.1, 120.1, 114.1, 118.6, 2.5]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```